# NgIf and click on same button on dialog

Tags: javascript, angular, forms, angular-material

I want make a form with error message if the name already exist or group not exist.
I have the error message from the server when I click on submit .
Now I close the dialog box with the on Close Confirm function.

```
      <button mat-raised-button class="createUserBtn" color="primary" type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid"   (click)="onCloseConfirm()">Save</button>
```

But now I have to click on save button , wait for the error message or not 
If message , display it and let the dialog open.
If no error message , execute the function on Close Confirm.

the problem I think I have , is async wait , I wait for server answer to check error or not and after close or not the dialog.

this is my function Submit

```
  error = false;
  errorMessage = '';

onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.fixtureService.create(this.form.value)
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          if (error.error.error ==='FIXTURE_NAME_TAKEN') {
            console.warn("Fixture name already exist");
            this.error = true;
            this.errorMessage = 'Fixture name already exist'
          } else if (error.error.error ==='GROUP_NOT_FOUND') {
            console.warn("Group selected doesn't exist");
            this.error = true;
            this.errorMessage = 'Group selected doesn\'t exist'
          } else onCloseConfirm();
}
```

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/12113249/s%c3%a9bastian Hi, you need to add a more descriptive title. It should state the problem or ask a question

Comment: what are you asking. I got no clue. is it you want to close the dialog right away on save or you want to wait till server response returns, you want to show a loader while the dialog is on??

Comment: No , I just check if error= true , if true display errorMessage

Comment: but to check if I have a error I need to submit

Comment: But for have the error, I have to submit to server. So I need to submit without closing, check if error, if not error close the dialog.